# I include Ws2tcpip.h but my compiler says inet_ntop is undeclared

Tags: c++, networking, winsock

I tried to compile some sample code from Beej's networking guide but my compiler is giving me the error "C:\Dev-Cpp\mainweq.cpp `inet_ntop' undeclared (first use this function)" even though I included ws2tcpip.h. Here is the code:

```
/*
** showip.c -- show IP addresses for a host given on the command line
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
WSADATA wsaData;

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

int iResult;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int iResult;

// Initialize Winsock
iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
if (iResult != 0) {
printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
return 1;
}

struct addrinfo hints, *res, *p;
int status;
char ipstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr,"usage: showip hostname\n");
    return 1;
}

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; // AF_INET or AF_INET6 to force version
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

if ((status = getaddrinfo(argv[1], NULL, &hints, &res)) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
    return 2;
}

printf("IP addresses for %s:\n\n", argv[1]);

for(p = res;p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) 
    {
    void *addr;
    char *ipver;

    // get the pointer to the address itself,
    // different fields in IPv4 and IPv6:
    if (p->ai_family == AF_INET) { // IPv4
        struct sockaddr_in *ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)p->ai_addr;
        addr = &(ipv4->sin_addr);
        ipver = "IPv4";
    } 
    else 
    { // IPv6
        struct sockaddr_in6 *ipv6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)p->ai_addr;
        addr = &(ipv6->sin6_addr);
        ipver = "IPv6";
    }

    // convert the IP to a string and print it:
    inet_ntop(p->ai_family, addr, ipstr, sizeof ipstr);
    printf("  %s: %s\n", ipver, ipstr);
}

freeaddrinfo(res); // free the linked list

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for inet_ntoa or WSAAddressToString or InetNtop?

More [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc805843%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: the ANSI version of InetNtop is inet_ntop, i tried both and neither worked, I'm looking for ntop not ntoa.

Comment: #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600 before the includes

Comment: @user1882226, if you don`t have >= Vista, you can use WSAAddressToString which is available from Windows 2000. Set _WIN32_WINNT to 0x0501(Xp) in this case. If none of this values work, you can set #define NTDDI_VERSION NTDDI_VISTA

Comment: Yeah I missed that bit, I'm using XP, I guess thats the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Beej doesn't say to include `ws2tcpip.h`. [He says](http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/inet_ntopman.html) to include `arpa/inet.h`.

But `inet_ntop` is a POSIX function. More likely, you're looking for a Windows equivalent such as `WSAAddressToString`.

Answer (score 0):

`inet_ntop` is not available on Windows until Vista. Avoid platform-specific functions if you can write portable code.

Here, use `getnameinfo` with `NI_NUMERICHOST` and no service, which is exactly equivalent to `inet_ntop` (but without as much nasty casting).

*Availability:* All unixes and Win2K+ have `getnameinfo`.

Comment: Windows Vista+ has [`InetNtop()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc805843.aspx).